# Can the heat pipes of a CPU cooling fan be trimmed?

Tags: cooling, cpu-cooler

I purchased a [Hyper 212 EVO](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-212-evo/) cooling fan for a PC I am building, but it turns out that it is just a little bit too big (by less than a centimeter) to fit in my case. It appears that in my case, if the heat pipes didn't stick out on the side opposite the CPU, it would fit in my case.

Is it possible to trim off that part of the heat pipes so that they are flush (or close to it) to the rest of the cooler?

Comment: You could attempt to do so, but I wouldn't attempt it, you are more likely to simply destroy the heatsink itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about that heat sink. But heat pipes have liquid inside of them. The liquid boils at the hot end and condenses on the cool end. This transfers the heat from one side to the other over a distance.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe

So, the most likely answer is NO. You would completely destroy the heat sink.

Comment: I suspected this would be the answer. There's not another easy way to gain an extra centimeter of room, is there?

Comment: @RobWatts  Lol. Did you buy a slim case? All normal towers should have plenty of room. No, I'm sorry. I don't think there is anyway of getting around this without exchanging parts. Are you planning on overclocking or something? If not, there isn't any need for an aftermarket heat sink. Just use a stock cooler. If you have a heat problem it will most likely be because of the smaller case.